# ¿Como cerrar la conexión a mi base de datos?

Tags: java, mysql

Hola quisiera saber porqué no se cierran las conexiones a mi base de datos(bueno ahora en ningun lado cierro la conexión), ya que estas se quedan en modo "sleep" y despues de un tiempo me sale el error de "too many connections"

tengo los siguientes archivos

DATConexion

```
package DAT;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DATConexion {
Connection con = null;
public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "password");
}
public Connection AbrirConexion() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    con = getConnection();
    return con;
}
public void CerrarConexion() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        con = null;

}
}
```

DATPrueba

```
package DAT;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DATPrueba {

DAT.DATConexion c = new DATConexion();

public ResultSet pruebaCarga() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Statement st = c.AbrirConexion().createStatement();
    String sentencia = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
    ResultSet re = st.executeQuery(sentencia);
    return re;
   }
}
```

BLPrueba

```
package BL;

import DAT.DATPrueba;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class BLPrueba {
DATPrueba manejadorPrueba = new DATPrueba();

public ArrayList<Object[]> verPrueba() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Object[]> datos = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = manejadorPrueba.pruebaCarga();
    ResultSetMetaData rm = rs.getMetaData();
    int col = rm.getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Object[] filas = new Object[col];
        for (int i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
            filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
        }
        datos.add(filas);
    }
    return datos;
  }
}
```

y en un Jframe se encuentra este metodo que me carga los datos en un jtable

```
public static void updateTabla() {
    try {
        BLPrueba dl = new BLPrueba();
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dtm.addColumn("Id");
        dtm.addColumn("Nombre");
        dtm.addColumn("Cedula");
        int aux = dl.verPrueba().size();
        System.out.println(aux);
        //for (int i = 0; i < dl.verPrueba().size(); i++) {
        for (int i =0 ; i < aux; i++) {
            dtm.addRow(dl.verPrueba().get(i));
        }

        tblPrueba.setModel(dtm);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(pruebagui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Cuando termines de leer los datos y no vayas a enviar más consultas deberías cerrar la conexión llamando a `c.CerrarConexion();`  suponiendo que la instancia de la clase se llama `c`.

Comment: cuando hago eso en la funcion de updateTabla me aparece "non-static variable c cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @A.Cedano ese método no cierra la conexión en absoluto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ entonces como debería cerrarla????

Comment: Llamando a `conn.close`.

Comment: Solo como comentario te recomiendo que siempre que puedas la cierres dentro del finally del try catch, y trata de nunca olvidar cerrar tambien los Statement, e visto muchas bases de datos que se cuelgan por estos motivos.

Answer (score 1):

Para el manejo de recursos de BD, crea un método que cierra las conexiones en la clase que contiene los parámetros de conexión y método de conexión [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close())

```
public void CerrarConexion() {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        Logger.getLogger(DATConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    }
}
```

Y para cerrar conexiones después de una consulta puedes usar el siguiente método. Pero para cerrar toda la conexión utiliza el método **CerrarConexion()**.

```
public void cierraConsultas() {
    try {
        if (Rs != null) {
            Rs.close();
        }
        if (St != null) {
            St.close();
        }
        if (Conector != null) {
            Conector.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClaseDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    }
}
```

Comment: El método CerrarConexion sigue sin cerrarme las conexiones ya que cuando reviso las conexiones en mi base de datos aparecen así
-- Connection Id: 1178-- User: root-- Host: localhost-- DB: prueba-- Command: Sleep-- Time: 7-- State: None
y como hay 142 registros en mi base me crea 142 conexiones y nunca desaparecen salvo que la aplicación se cierre

Answer (score 0):

Usa el método [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) :

```
   public void CerrarConexion() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

         if (con != null) {
            con.close(); //*Cierra conexión.
         }

    }
```

---

> [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) : libera esta base de datos de objetos de Connection y
>   recursos JDBC de forma inmediata en lugar de esperar que se liberen
>   automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

En tu codigo:

```
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(pruebagui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} //agregar aqui
```

Agrega la siguiente linea

```
finally{
     if (con != null) {
        con.close(); //Cierra la conexion y libera el recurso
     }
}
```